# How would I go about remapping this UV

Tags: mesh, uv

I've imported a model but the UV has made the mesh have two faces.
What's the best way to fix this or is there a tutorial on fixing imported UVs?

[image]

[image]7.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have imported the mesh, then maybe it's just how this UV is supposed to be used.
It looks like the problematic area is where there's supposed to be hairs. My guess is that the texture you're using isn't used on that area.

Then, either it's a matter of different UV sets, in which case you just might check in your object's Data tab if you have several UVs, and unse them accordingly in your material :
[image]

Either you just have to select those faces, and assign them to another material :
[image]

Or maybe both.

Comment: I've just tried what you said and that doesn't appear to have worked, there is also only one UV. I've tried looking closer at the UVs and it kinda looks like the scalp UV is just covering the face as well.  Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: Yes, use different materials for the head and the hair area like I explained.

Comment: yeah, I just realized my mistake, sorry. I managed to do it wrong. sorry. thank you for your help

Comment: you welcome ! ^^